# HTML email - td not aligning properly

Tags: html, email

I'm building an html only eBlast. I have on table that lives inside of a  which holds body copy. It is pushing itself outside of the containing table. How can I make this sit inside the container where it is supposed to be?

Here's what it's doing: http://zachkeller.net/annie_moses/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
  <title>The Song of Annie Moses</title>

  <style type="text/css">

    #backgroundTable {
      table-layout:fixed;
      width: 650px;
      background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="750px" width="650px"   id="backgroundTable">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" height="125px" width="650">
        <img src="images/headline.png">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="220px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="220px" height="375">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="images/cover.png">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td width="430px">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="430px" height="375">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>The Song of Annie Moses tells of a miraculous musical journey spanning four generations that brought a family to The Julliard School and world stages, including Carnegie Hall. The story is one of God plowing a path, and shaping their music and message for his purpose. Discover that God has placed within all of us a calling to express what we know with beauty and wonder.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img src="images/band.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <p>The Annie Moses Band is a Christian family of Juilliard trained musicians dedicated to virtuosity in the arts. Add the veteran, award-winning, song writing talents of their parents, Bill and Robin Wolaver, and you have a dynamic group with roots in classical, pop, and jazz.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `colspan="2"` to all your `<td>` elements, which take the full width..

Moreover your HTML-Code is not good at all. Two important things: for html `width`-attribute you don't need `px` after the number. The second thing is, that you are creating a full `<table>` for only one `<p>`-Element.. I don't know why you are doing this..

This is the full code, which should work.. I fixed some other things, although it's still not perfect:

```
<html><head>
  <title>The Song of Annie Moses</title>

  <style type="text/css">

    #backgroundTable {
      table-layout:fixed;
      width: 650px;
      background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="750px" width="650px" id="backgroundTable">
    <tbody><tr><td width="250"></td><td width="400"></td><tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" height="125" width="650" colspan="2">
        <img src="images/headline.png">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="images/cover.png">
      </td>

      <td>

              <p>The Song of Annie Moses tells of a miraculous musical journey spanning four generations that brought a family to The Julliard School and world stages, including Carnegie Hall. The story is one of God plowing a path, and shaping their music and message for his purpose. Discover that God has placed within all of us a calling to express what we know with beauty and wonder.</p>

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <img src="images/band.jpg">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <p>The Annie Moses Band is a Christian family of Juilliard trained musicians dedicated to virtuosity in the arts. Add the veteran, award-winning, song writing talents of their parents, Bill and Robin Wolaver, and you have a dynamic group with roots in classical, pop, and jazz.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I'm basically just trying anything to get this to work.... I tried adding the <p> in it's own table to see if it would help

Comment: Well, the problem was that before the book's td's width was the full width of your background. That's why the text moved outside.. If it works, please don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: Ok, I've used your code, but i cant make one column sit at 220 and the other one sit at 430. They both are split down the middle at 325px each.... http://zachkeller.net/annie_moses/index.html

Comment: Okay I see. I'll try to fix this

Comment: The problem is, that the width of an `td` element can only be set ONCE. So every following change of the width is ignored. As the first td are two merged cells, it splitted the td's width. Now I added two empty td's with your desired width at the beginning, and it's width is applied to the lower ones. But all these problems you wouldn't have if you weren't using tables (what is btw. not a good way). So maybe you should try to do all this with `div` elements rather than using a table. I'll try to rewrite your full code, just give me a second^^

Comment: This is the same thing written in a bit better code: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ad3/2/

Comment: Well i can't use divs, as this is an html only email. If I could use divs, I wouldnt have this problem. The specs of this eBlast require html only, in tables, no divs and only inline css....

Answer (score 1):

Tables need to have equal number of columns per row. Row 2 has two columns, while all other rows have one. Remove the inner tables, set border=1 and you can easily see where your table is broken. As **kostyan** says above, you need to add colspans.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="750px" width="650px"   id="backgroundTable">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" height="125px" width="650">
        A
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="220px">
        B
      </td>

      <td width="430px">
       C
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        D
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        E
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: totally beat me to it.  tables inside of Tables, ugh. once you remove the inside tables though this is the best way to implement a table for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

need to set colspan correctly, your second row has 2 cells but rest only one

```
<td colspan="2"...
```

Comment: so, the first td in the row would be colspan="1", and the second with the body copy would be colspan="2" ??

Comment: colspan = 1 is automatic, by default.

Comment: other way around, 1 cell columns need to have colspan="2"